# Fallback background-image if default doesn't exist

Tags: html, css, background

I want to set an image as a background, however the image name might be either `bg.png` or `bg.jpg`.

Is there any non-javascript way to create a fallback to an alternative image if the default background doesn't exist?

```
body{
    background: url(bg.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the desired behavior if the image **doesn't** exist?

Comment: i will add a file uploader and the uploader will accept png or jpg. based on the image that will be uploaded it will set the file as bg.png or bg.jpg

Comment: you can add `data-fallback` attribute to body tag and then check  `var body = $(document.body);` `if(!(body.css('background'))) {body.css('background', body.data('fallback ')) }`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use multiple backgrounds if there is no transparency involved and they occupy all available space or have the same size:

```css
div{   
     background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1000x1000'), url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-size: 100%;
     height:200px;
     width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If the first doesn't exit, the second will be displayed.

```css
div{   
     background-image: url('http://placehol/1000x1000'), url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-size: 100%;
     height:200px;
     width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I accepted his answer at the moment he answered. After that I noticed that you answered with the same solution. Thanks again

Comment: When I write my answer the other answer was diferent but if you want change your vote not problem for me, I try to help, don't worry the reputation.

Comment: Nah, it's okay. My edit and your answer were only 4 minutes apart :)

Comment: what if there is transparency tho?

Comment: The images are stacked, if the top one has transparency will see the bottom image through

Comment: What is the browser compatibility?

Comment: @CrystalMiller You can see here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds

Comment: Unfortunately, on chrome - network tab - I can see it loads both images from the server. Even when the first is successful.

Comment: @MartinCapodici Yes,  that is the expected behavior for multiple backgrounds, is not a replacement of images.

Comment: Browser loads both images. Would be nice if the second gets only loaded if the first one failed. Afaik, not possible with this solution.

Comment: Not at all, that's the [expected behaviour of multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_backgrounds_and_borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds), they are stacked. Nonetheless a standard way for fallback images would be much appreciated; something like `background-fallback: url(...), url(...);` matching `background-image` entries index, just like the other `background-*` properties.

Answer (score 19):

To specify multiple possible backgrounds, you could do:

```
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url('bg.png'), url('bg.jpg');
```

This will set the background to `bg.png` if it exists. If it doesn't exist, it will be set to `bg.jpg`. If none of those images exist, the background will be set to the static `green` color.

Note that it will prioritize whatever image is specified first. So if both images exist, it will display the `bg.png` on top of the `bg.jpg`. If the png has any transparency, both images will be partially visible.

Check out the [**demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/po758hv7/2/). Test it by breaking any of the image urls'.

Comment: its not the solution that I need but I just up-voted for the alternative solution.

Comment: @djsony90 Oh, so the image will always exist, but it will either be a `jpg` OR `png`?

Comment: sorry, I didn't specified. The uploader will delete the existing bg.png or bg.jpg then will update a new one bg.png or bg.jpg

Comment: As @blonfu mentioned in a different answer, both images are loaded and stacked.  It does not just load the first successful file.

Comment: @J.Hendrix right, but there is no other way to solve that without JavaScript. OP asked for a "non-javascript way" and this is probably as good as it gets with css-only. Unless I'm missing something (if so please specify what), I think the down-vote isn't quite justified since there is no other way, really, to solve this.

Comment: To be clear, the statement "If [the first image] doesn't exist, it will be set to [second image]" is false; the images and colors are all loaded and stacked. In this example, bg.png will display on top, then bg.jpg, and finally a green background. Since all images take the full background, we don't see the other layers.

Comment: Because background images aren't guaranteed to be the same size, or you might be using an image with transparency (e.g. in an SVG); in such a case, you would see underlying the images/background-color.

Comment: I understand the OP use case; I still find this answer misleading.

Comment: Why? The answer was updated to be clearer and I explained that this isn't a canonical answer, but an answer specifically to OP's problem. OP also specifically asked for a CSS-only solution which most other answers here disregarded. If you think the answer is misleading still, you ask specifically what needs to be made more clear and I will update it once more.

Comment: @Chris, I now see your recent update and agree that it improves clarity. I still think the statement "This will set the background to `bg.png` if it exists. If it doesn't exist, it will be set to `bg.jpg`." is misleading - it sounds like it only displays the second image if the first wasn't available (which is not what you say in the following paragraph now).

Comment: This actually really worked well for me and turned out to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Although this solution does involve JS, it will download the first image using CSS, and will **only** use JS to download the fallback image if the main image failed to download.

First, set the main image with CSS as usual, for example:

```css
.myImage {
    background-image = "main-image.png";
}
```

And add the following JS that will only act if loading the main image fails (otherwise, fallback image will never be downloaded).

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.onerror = function() {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = '.myImage { background-image = url("http://fallback_image.png"); }';
    document.head.appendChild(style);
}
img.src = "main_image.png";
```

Note that you can add multiple rules to the CSS block added with javascript, for example if you need to do this with multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can have background image with css and use the same image URL in a hidden image tag and onError, change the image URL and make it show it

```
<div
  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageSrc})` }}
>
  <img
    style={{ display: "none" }}
    src={imageSrc}
    onError={(e) => {
      e.currentTarget.src = brokenImageFallbackUrl;
      e.currentTarget.style.display = "block";
      // or keep this image hidden and set the backgroundImage of the parent div
    }}
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have a solution that doesn't load the images twice. For example CDN with a fallback is not very good if it always loads the original images also. So I ended up writing a Javascript to manipulate the loaded CSS DOM.

```
var cdn = "https://mycdn.net/"; // Original location or thing to find
var localImageToCssPath = "../"; // Replacement, Css are in /css/ folder.

function replaceStyleRule(allRules){
  var rulesCount = allRules.length;

  for (var i=0; i < rulesCount; i++) 
  {
    if(allRules[i].style !== undefined && allRules[i].style !== null &&
        allRules[i].style.backgroundImage !== undefined &&
        allRules[i].style.backgroundImage !== null &&
        allRules[i].style.backgroundImage !== "" &&
        allRules[i].style.backgroundImage !== "none" &&
        allRules[i].style.backgroundImage.indexOf(cdn) > -1
            )
      {
        var tmp = allRules[i].style.backgroundImage.replace(cdn, localImageToCssPath);
        //console.log(tmp);
        allRules[i].style.backgroundImage = tmp;
      }
      if(allRules[i].cssRules !== undefined && allRules[i].cssRules !== null){
        replaceStyleRule(allRules[i].cssRules);
      }

  }
}
function fixBgImages(){
  var allSheets = document.styleSheets;
  if(allSheets===undefined || allSheets===null){
    return;
  }
  var sheetsCount = allSheets.length;
  for (var j=0; j < sheetsCount; j++) 
  {
    var allRules = null;
    try{
        allRules = allSheets[j].cssRules;
    } catch(e){
        // Access can be denied
    }
    if(allRules!==undefined && allRules!==null){
        replaceStyleRule(allRules);
    }
  }
}

// use fixBgImages() in e.g. onError
```