# Fallback for GCP Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to build a website where I would like to leverage Google Cloud Storage to serve static assets. But want any resource which is not found in the bucket should fallback to my webserver. Is there a way to specify a fallback for the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done by changing the [404.html](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web) on Cloud Storage to contain a redirect to another webpage.

You do this by adding in the [header](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_redirect.cfm):

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=https://example.com">
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few client side JavaScript/css ways to do this. For example https://medium.com/@webcore1/react-fallback-for-broken-images-strategy-a8dfa9c1be1e or [Fallback background-image if default doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588017/fallback-background-image-if-default-doesnt-exist)