# CSS background-image fallback

Tags: html, css, fallback, webp

Is there any way to specify a fallback image for a background image using CSS?

Example

```
.container {
  background-image: url(pics/img.webp);
  background-image-fallback: url(pics/img.png);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fallback background-image if default doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588017/fallback-background-image-if-default-doesnt-exist)

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy not really

Comment: Simply stating your question is not a duplicate without explaining **why** it is not a duplicate will not succeed in getting your question reopened.

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple images if the one doesn't exit, the second will be show.

```
.container {
      background-image: url(pics/img.webp), url(pics/img.png);
    }
```

Comment: technically speaking, this is not a fallback because the browser will try to load all the images

Comment: Agree with you Temani afif

Comment: Yes, it will affect the page speed, as the browser tries to load both the images. The idea of specifying a fallback is to provide an alternative for an image if it could not be loaded, not load both. I am currently using this syntax but the Google PageSpeed test tool (Lighthouse) recommends providing a fallback what so ever. Should i look towards writing a different markup, or is there a way to specify the fallback while only using CSS? Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```
.container {
  background: url((pics/img.webp) bottom center no-repeat,url((pics/img.webp) repeat;
}
```