# Is there a way to detect if background image loaded properly or not in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 7 app in which I am displaying a `div` background image. But sometimes link is broken.

My image is bound in my HTML like this

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + row?.coverUrl + ')', 'background-size': 'cover', 'background-position' : 'center'}" class="img-area cursor-pointer" (click)="navigateToCOmpany(row)" *ngIf="row.coverUrl !== ''">
</div>
```

The problem is that sometimes `row?.coverUrl` is broken link. So how can I detect that link is broken so that I can bind a default image?

Comment: As an option invoke a `get` request to the background image url and in case it succeed, all things are ok. In case it errored - you have a problem case.

Comment: I don't think it's the proper way to do this. Because if i do like this so for each time for each image will i be hitting one extra get call? Don't you think it will create server overhead?

Comment: `get` requests are cached by server usually.And it should not make a sufficient overhead if your images are not 1gb in size.

Comment: row?.coverUrl - is internal url or external ?

Comment: @MilanRaval external url that might be expire after sometime.

Comment: You can take @Rafael's idea and use a HEAD request instead, which will be much lighter-weight, but still tell you whether the image exists or not.

Comment: Answer to this question looks similar, it has another URL as fallback : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588017/fallback-background-image-if-default-doesnt-exist

Comment: @HereticMonkey how can i make a http request for image?

Comment: Ajax; You're using Angular, so HttpClient is the way to go.

Comment: @HereticMonkey i tried this 

`get = (): Observable<any> => {
        return this._http.get(`https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg`, { headers: this.getHeaders()})
  }`

But on subscribing to it each time i am getting an error

Comment: see this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjavzx

Comment: Sounds like a different problem (likely CORS). Do some research on the error you are getting, and if you can't find anything, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are some workarounds which you can use:

1. Use an invisible img tag (as suggested by user3723763) and in the
   error handler update the row.coverUrl which will update your DIV's background image also.
2. Multiple URLs can be passed in
   the background-image, pass the fallback image as the 2nd URL and it
   will start showing if the first one breaks. **NOTE:** this will
   correctly work only if your images are not transparent, refer the
   sample code from here: [2 URLs as background-image](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ghfdb?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no professional solution I still wanted to show the different ways if you like you can use it.

```
<div [ngStyle]="backgroundObj" class="img-area cursor-pointer"></div>
<img hidden [src]="brokenImageUrl" (error)="doSomethingOnError($event)" />



  brokenImageUrl = null // or try -> 'https://placebeard.it/640x360'; 
  brokeImage =
    'https://serpstat.com/img/blog/how-to-detect-broken-images-on-the-website/16451874451570033394image1-min.png';
  image = 'https://placebeard.it/640x360';
  backgroundObj = {
    width: '500px',
    height: '500px',
    'background-image': 'url(' + this.image + ')',
    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
  };
  

  doSomethingOnError(event: any) {
    if (event) {
      this.backgroundObj = {
        width: '500px',
        height: '500px',
        'background-image': 'url(' + this.brokeImage + ')',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
      };
    }
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://angular7-playground-rvgk4v.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution for your problem

```
 <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + row.coverUrl? row.coverUrl : 
  deafultUrl + ')', 'background-size': 'cover', 'background-position' : 
  'center'}" class="img-area cursor-pointer" 
  (click)="navigateToCOmpany(row)" *ngIf="row.coverUrl !== ''">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have an image with a spinner while loading. For this, I used an `Image` to load the image, and once loaded, I made a data URL from it that I passed to the `<img>`. Given this method, I knew exactly when the image was loading, loaded or errored.

Just be wary when changing image to same URL, it might get confused.