# Fallback on background-color when background-image is null React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image-fallback

Creating a `React` component where I am trying to use `css` property of `background-color` to fall back when `background-image` is `null` as I could see one of the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37588077/1108500). The code only works if there is any image, but when there is no image it doesn't fall back to `background-color` and shows an error `undefined:1 GET http://localhost:3000/undefined 404 (Not Found)`. What am I missing?

```
const BoxModule = ({
  backgroundColor,
  BackgroundImage,

}) => {

const imageFormats = BackgroundImage?.formats;
const imageSrc = formatImage({ formats: imageFormats });

if (!BackgroundImage || !BackgroundImage?.url) {
  return null;
}

return (
 <Section
   backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
   backgroundImageUrl={imageSrc}
 >
 ...
 </Section>
); 

export default BoxModule;
 
const Section = styled(Section)`
  background-color: ${(p) => p.backgroundColor};
  background-image: ${(p) => `url('${p.backgroundImageUrl}')`};
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;
```

**[Updated error trace]**

I can only see the error as shown below:

[image]

Is this error because the code is trying to process the `image` which fails due to the `null` value and therefore doesn't fall back to `bacground-color`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code was enough to fallback on `background-color`. Issue was not this, something else. So to answer this particular issue the following code is enough. Don't even need and null conditional check for the `background-image`.

```
const Section = styled(Section)`
background-color: ${(p) => p.backgroundColor};
background-image: ${(p) => `url('${p.backgroundImageUrl}')`};
background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;
```